# displaying website on online server

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, web

i have a simple website with bootstrap and some graphic frameworks

my site load normal on my PC and everything is good nut when i want to load it from my online server i have some problems . look at these pictures

**PC**

[image]

**Online**

[image]

What is the problem? i checked directory to be sure CSS files be here and everything is OK. I can't understand the reason of my problem

**Update:**
I have some errors in my console about fonts . what about this ?

[image]

Comment: The online version [http://arash-hatami.ir](http://arash-hatami.ir) looks the same as the first picture to me

Comment: really ??? :| :| so why looks bad for me ? i try loading the site in different browsers @Simplicity

Comment: I confirm on-line work perfectly like the first picture..

Comment: Tested in Chrome, Firefox & Microsoft Edge all look like the first picture

Comment: Try checking the console for any errors which may cause this to happen, first thought: bootstrap failed to load

Comment: Press CNTRL+F5 to refresh the page, maybe a cache issue

Comment: i tried that way ... nothing @AdamBuchananSmith

Comment: @Simplicity post modified included console output

Comment: Fonts shouldn't mess up your layout that bad

Comment: i have no idea any more .... Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Android, ... everywhere looks that for me @Simplicity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the reason of this problem

My codes and also directory or loading files have not any problem. when i checked my website's source code i saw that my code changed.

some month ago i used [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) for my **Wordpress** site and i have not any problem with that. but now when i want to load a Bootstrap site, i have this problem.

last night i changed DNS's and problem fixed
I don't know why but [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) is the reason of all problems. I should contact them

Thank you my friends

Answer (score 1):

I've been going through your code through the Chrome developers console and after removing the class `col-md-4-` from your `<div class="col-md-4 service animated fadeInRight visible" data-animation="fadeInRight" data-animation-delay="800">` it changed to what your second image is showing.

Somewhere along the line there's something going wrong with Bootstrap's `col-md-4` classes on your `<div>`

[image: Screenshot website with console]

**The three circled divs are your contact divs, as you can see I've removed the `col-md-4` class of the first one**

I wish I could be of more help.

Comment: I believe so @ArashHatami

Comment: i saw `style` section of developers window. there isn't `col-md-4` class

Comment: Don't look at the `style` section, look at the HTML code and check the contact `<div>`

Comment: OMG !! my offline code is very different. why ???????????????????????? http://i.imgur.com/qJ2BI2Z.jpg